# fabric center all objects as group

Tags: javascript, html, html5-canvas, fabricjs

I recently started to work with fabricjs, and I have a question about groups. I would like to center all objects (many) when canvas is resized. So I tought to build a group with all objects in my canvas and center it.

However, in order to do that, I have to:

- retrieve all objects
- add them to my group
- remove them from my canvas
- add the group to my canvas

A complex process, and, above all, my objects lost the possibility to be manipulate individually.

I am wondering if it is possible to manipulate a group without add it in my canvas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code should work with fabric 2.0 beta.
A similar code is possible for the version 1.7.x and you can create from this using the activeGroup logic.

What you may want to do is:

```
// After the canvas resize:
// get all Objects:
var objects = canvas.getObjects();
// create a multiselection
var selection = new fabric.ActiveSelection(objects, { canvas: canvas });
// now get size of this selection:
var width = selection.width;
var height = selection.height;
// scale the selection accordingly
var scale = ( find the right scale value, probably canvas.width/width or canvas.height/height. The biggest or smaller of them )
selection.scale(scale);
// center the selection in the canvas
selection.center();
// destroy the selection
selection.destroy();
```

And this should be working.

Answer (score 0):

Do you need the group? Or you are just creating them to center the objects? If not, you can use `object.center()` for each one of the canvas object you want to center in screen.

```
canvas.forEachObject(function (o) {
    o.center();
});
```

Comment: Hi, actually I don't need the group. However solution you proposed center every single object, whereas I want to center them "as a group" (I want to preserve the distance among each object).

Comment: Ok i understand, so.. you dont want to center the objects, you need to "resize" them as the canvas resize? Like a zooming functionality?